# Cloud Data Fusion - Secret Manager integration

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion, google-secret-manager

I am building a Cloud Data Fusion pipeline where I will be connecting to Database to pull the data. The requirement is to keep the Database user id and password in GCP Secret manager. How do I read these details as part of macro? If it is not possible what is the work around?
[image]

Answer (score 4):

You may want to look into using the [Secure Macro](https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/1188036697/Macros+and+macro+functions#Secure-Function). Cloud Data Fusion unfortunately does not have integration with GCP Secret Manager; instead, it uses Cloud KMS to store secrets.

Creating, retrieving, and storing secure keys can be done via the REST API as described in the [Secure Storage API docs](https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/477790661/Security+Microservices#Secure-Storage).

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.
once you created the key in the Admin Console,
get the key name and use it inside the macro with this format. ${secure(key name)}
https://jtaras.medium.com/google-data-fusion-securing-your-access-keys-and-passwords-267c85f9fb1